# CSV columnar reformat with SED (or anything other coreutil)

Tags: text-processing, sed

Given the following made-up segment from an output file from hashdeep:

```
7241,11111111111111111111111111111111,\01-data\file1
1237241,22222222222222222222222222222222,\01-data\file2
41,33333333333333333333333333333333,\01-data\file3
```

How would I get about it to format it like:

```
   7241,11111111111111111111111111111111,\01-data\file1
1237241,22222222222222222222222222222222,\01-data\file2
     41,33333333333333333333333333333333,\01-data\file3
```

I'd like to use sed (as that's what I'm beginning to get to grips with), but is there a way to tell sed to only change characters if they occur in a specific column or specific columns?

Of course if there is another way to do it, I'd be just as happy to hear about that.

The reason for this is that I want to sort the output on the filenames, so that I can compare two output files, without having to use the `-j0` (single-thread) option on hashdeep.

Comment: Probably not applicable for this case, but a general tool for this *type* of formatting is `column`.

Comment: I'm perhaps missing something, but you want to sort on file names as in `sort -t, -k3 filename` ?

Comment: I've had a look at sort and it does indeed what is needed, but coming from the z/OS world, it's feels very, very unnatural to sort on fields rather than positions.

Comment: This is an XY problem. You don't need to reformat your CSV in order to sort your data at all.

Answer (score 8):

With `awk`:

```
awk -v l="$(wc -L <file)" '{printf "%"l"s\n", $0}' file
```

- `-v` assigns an external value to an `awk` variable `l`.

  - `wc -L <file` find the length of the longest line in the file.
- `printf "%"l"s\n", $0` prints each line space padded with by `l` spaces. For 10 spaces, it would for example look like: `printf "%10s\n", $0`.

---

The output:

```
   7241,11111111111111111111111111111111,\01-data\file1
1237241,22222222222222222222222222222222,\01-data\file2
     41,33333333333333333333333333333333,\01-data\file3
```

Comment: Nice one. A slightly more readable version would arguably contain `{printf "%*s\n", l, $0}`. It also works with `gawk --posix`, so I guess it is not `gawk`'s invention.

Answer (score 6):

```sh
sed -e:, -e's/^[^,]\{0,6\},/ &/;t,'
```

It just does a little loop until there are at least 7 not-commas at the head of a line. It only does anything at all, though, if there are fewer than 7 not-commas already there which are immediately followed by a comma. And so it doesn't affect blank lines or lines which do not match a comma, or those that do but already start with 7 or more not-commas.

The loop is really cheap, too - the automaton only needs to consider two kinds of characters - those that are or are not commas - and only 7 of those at maximum at any given time.

---

```
   7241,11111111111111111111111111111111,\01-data\file1
1237241,22222222222222222222222222222222,\01-data\file2
     41,33333333333333333333333333333333,\01-data\file3
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using `sed`. I copied your input and pasted into Libreofffice Calc, selected the "separate by comma" option in "Paste Special" and that put each data type into separate columns as shown below.

Very simple solution I think.

```
7241    11111111111111100000000000000000    \01-data\file1 

1237241 22222222222222200000000000000000    \01-data\file2

41      33333333333333300000000000000000    \01-data\file3
```

Comment: This is an understandable error, but somewhat horrifying.  Manipulating data and text on the command line never ever requires opening up a GUI.  I like LibreOffice quite well, but the tool for the job is `awk`, which is a super-advanced "spreadsheet" for the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question, but I think you just want to sort by filename? In that case, just use `sort`:

```
sort -t , -k 3 my_file.txt
```